# Where Did Gnome Go?

Tags: centos, gnome3, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, gnome-keyring

Gnome is no longer running. I migrated hardware to a new tower and moved `/var` to a new harddrive nvme0n1p3/nvmeVg-var.  I believe this is the root of the issue.

when I type `gnome-session --version` the command goes through but no result.  This tells me gnome is no longer installed. Which I don't understand how.  After I run `gnome-session --version` then `echo $?` = `0`

Using CentOS7 (server+GUI)

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0   446G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  31.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:5    0 364.5G  0 lvm  

nvme0n1         259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   953M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-var  253:2    0    50G  0 lvm  /var
```

so what I did, was make a Logical Volume on nvmeVg, then formatted and mounted it on a temporary mount point, (note, that we were in single-user mode (aka recovery mode) at the time), then I copied the data in `/var`, then stored on `/`, to the new logical volume... after that, I removed the stuff in the original copy of `/var` (it was like 25g). then mounted the new logical volume on `/var`, and adjusted `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/centos/root /              xfs defaults    0 0
UUID=7d8928c4-baa1-4eaa-a13c-e937031f8dfa /boot xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=1078-26A1          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home /home                   ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
#/dev/mapper/orca-home  /data           xfs defaults    0 0
#/dev/md0       /mnt/raid5      ext4    defaults    0 0
#/dev/sdb1      /borg           ext4    defaults    0 0
/dev/nvmeVg/var     /var            ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: Which distro are you using?  Also, it might be good to understand how you've changed your mount-points.  Can you post the output of `lsblk`?  Also, after running `gnome-session --version` what is the output of `echo $?`?

Comment: updated to address your questions

Comment: I said "`echo $?`", not "`echo $`?". `echo $?` gives the return code of the previous process.  I was curious if `gnome-session` returned a non-zero exit code.  How did you move `/var` to the new harddrive?  I would expect you would boot into a live-CD so `/` and `/var` are not mounted, then do the copy.  If `/` was mounted, you could run into problems.

Comment: updated added fstab as well

Comment: How did you copy the data into the new /var?  What commands did you run?

Comment: not sure man this was a week or two ago and was a learning experience for me.

Comment: Most likely you broke the OS in a way that the graphical login no longer starts.  What is happening when you boot?

Comment: I just rebooted and now I see a start job I haven't seen before "svscan.service".  Looks like devices are being unmounted now.  I have added this photo to the post above.
The OS loads a black screen now.  

Booting in emergency mode dracut lines are coming up and ends up in the dracut line. When I reboot A start job starts running dev-mapper-nvmeVg\x2droot.device I will load image above

Comment: just need to press cntl + alt + f2 to get to login screen so need to get gnome working

Comment: I took the advice from a skilled colleague and "sudo yum install --reinstall gnome-session" and got: "error: db5 error(11) from dbenv->open: Resources temporarily unavailable.  error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Resources temporarily unavailable(11) error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm"